# How to read a csv file with multiple header rows into pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, header, jupyter-notebook

I am not sure how to read the multiple rows. Do i have to do it without the rows and then do it manually in pandas? Or is there a way to read the whole csv file into pandas?

This is how the file looks 
[Poverty data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGTeF.png)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need parameter `header=[0,1]` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: I tried that then this error came up "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 107, saw 3"

Comment: It seems there are bad data, can you check line 107? Or is possible remove all problematic rows?

Comment: If need remove problematic rows need [error_bad_lines=False](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#handling-bad-lines)

Comment: I tried doing this, but it is taking my first column as the index. How do I fix it?

Comment: @TRISABISWAS - It is pain, mainly it depends of data, try `index_col=[0]`

Comment: index_col=[0] and index_col=None both are giving me same result.

Comment: I did a workaround by adding an index column in my excel sheet. Please let me know if there is any other efficient way to achieve this using pandas. Thank you.

Comment: @TRISABISWAS - really hard way, because it depends of data, so find working solution is problem.... I have no another idea like `index_col=[0]`, so sorry :(